# Open a tree view for several IDs after user press a button in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo 10, if I do this in a button handler:

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'res_model': 'purchase.order',
    'res_id': po_obj.id,
    'view_id': self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_form').id,
    'target': 'current',
}
```

I open a purchase order form for the **po_obj** id.

If instead of just one Purchase Order ID, I have several IDs, how could I open a tree view for those Purchase Orders IDs?

Answer (score 2):

Use `domain`:

```py
    return {
        'name': 'Purchase Orders',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'purchase.order',
        'domain': [('id', 'in', list_of_ids)],
        'target': 'main',
    }
```